# While installing appcelerator studio in windows for titanium, node js not installed correctly error

Tags: appcelerator

I don't have previously installed version of node in my system.

When I try to install Appcelerator Studio in windows, I keep getting this error

> NoteJS mandatory prerequisite was not correctly installed.

[image: When I try to install Appcelerator Studio in windows, I keep getting this error]

Comment: [Issue closed by Appcelerator on Nov 24 2015 as "Cannot Reproduce anymore".](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7869)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you've already reported this on JIRA (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7869) and it seems this is a regression of https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-6618 so I hope we'll be able to fix it soon. Please follow progress on JIRA.